# Adding scroll down button to Shopify custom theme

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am customizing shopify motion theme. I added a scroll down svg on bottom of the slider. But having problem with scrolling down to the next section

I have added the scroll down button with that code;

```
div.hero__image-wrapper:after {
    content:  url({{ "icon-scroll-down.svg" | asset_url }}) ;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 34560;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 48%;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;

    border: 3px solid gray;
    padding: 0.1em 0.1em 0;

    animation-name: color_change;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes color_change {
    0%  { color: gray;  bottom:20px;}
    10% { color: black; bottom:10px;}
    20% { color: gray;  bottom:20px;}
    100%{ color: gray;  bottom:20px;}
}
```

But currently it's only an icon. I need to make it scroll to down

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with JS instead. Let's assume your button is an actual element instead of pseudo `::after`:

```
<div class="scroll-down-button"></div>
```

```
.scroll-down-button {
  // whatever style you prefer
}
```

Then the JS code would look like this:

```
(function() {
    // Get the button element
    var button = document.querySelector('.scroll-down-button');

    // Get current section
    var currentSection = button.closest('.shopify-section');

    // Get next section (the very next element after current section container)
    var nextSection = currentSection.nextSibling();

    // Get the coordinates of the next section
    var nextSectionCoordinates = nextSection.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Get the top Y axis coordinates of next section
    var nextSectionTop = nextSectionCoordinates.top;

    // Scroll to the top of next section (0 means no scroll on X axis)
    window.scrollTo(0, nextSectionTop);
})();
```

The above is not tested, so let me know if it doesn't work or you can `console.log` any values. You should get the idea though!